# streaming live video after OpenCV image processing

Tags: c++, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

i am trying to stream live video feed from a camera connected to a Jetson NX, to a computer connected to the same network, the network works as wireless ethernet, meaning the jetson sees it as wired connection but in reality its wireless and is limited by bitrate.

On the jetson side, I am using OpenCV VideoWrite to send frames over the network using this pipeline:

```
    cv::VideoWriter video_write("appsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx  ! nvvidconv\
 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12,width=640,height=360,framerate=30/1 ! nvv4l2h264enc insert-sps-pps=1 insert-vui=1 idrinterval=30 \
 bitrate=1800000 EnableTwopassCBR=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=169.254.84.2 port=5004 auto-multicast=0",\
 cv::CAP_GSTREAMER,30,cv::Size(640,360));
```

on the receiving computer my video capture is :

```
cv::VideoCapture video("udpsrc port=5004 auto_multicast=0 !
 application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=0 !
 rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1 "
, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER);
```

Problem is, if the camera jitters a lot or moves a lot to any direction, the video stream either freezes or completely pixelates. I was hoping I could get suggestions for either a better encoder(im not limited to nvv4l2h264enc or h264 in general) or a solution for the pixaltion and freeze, or maybe even a better way to stream the video other than VideoWrite.

I am trying to stream 360p video at 30fps, my bitrate is limited to either 6mbps or 2.5mbps depending on the distance i want to limit myself at. it does not seem like a network problem simply because If i change parameters like Codec(MJPG instead of gstreamer for example) it changes the behaviour of the video feed, in my case it lowers the amount of freezing but makes the pixelating worse.

Comment: Does the pipeline work the same from command line?

Comment: i haven't tried using gst-launch, it will require a bit of trial and error when it comes to changing the pipeline to fit clean gstreamer without opencv but i will try it